# google maps activity some kind of a bug

Tags: java, android

I'm using android studio to create an app, and so I implemented the google maps into my application and everything is working fine, all the implementation are there I triple checked, everything needed for it to operate is there, but my problem is that when I close my application for a long time and reopen the maps activity the fragment showing to me is a random one, no markers no locate button no objects just an empty map with the name of the countries. So I open the google maps application(official application) and close it, then try to reopen my google maps activity and everything reverts to normal, markers showing images are displayed, all the functions operate normally can someone tell me what may be the problem **keep in mind** everything is added, from an API key to the implementations in the graddle.app and the graddle.app.appname , and in the manifest the metadata is added and so on...thank you !

**this is my map activity code where I added some NGOs locations and their images on the map:**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ICameraUpdateFactoryDelegate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;


public class map_act extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fetchLastLocation();
    }

    private void fetchLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    currentLocation = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(map_act.this);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,12));
        LatLng Unicef1 = new LatLng(33.887837297007835, 35.50965848465925 );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Unicef1).title("Unicef")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.unicef1)));
        LatLng Unicef2 = new LatLng(33.8865888125746, 35.48744276242378 );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Unicef2).title("Unicef")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.unicef1)));
        LatLng Unicef3 = new LatLng( 34.42414282398606, 35.82587499823564 );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Unicef3).title("Unicef")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.unicef1)));
        LatLng Unicef4 = new LatLng(33.27906495185468, 35.215073956249924 );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Unicef4).title("Unicef")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.unicef1)));

        LatLng Wvision1 = new LatLng(33.86913267946954, 35.576261865395736 );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Wvision1).title("World Vision")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.worldvision1)));
        LatLng Wvision2 = new LatLng(33.852201737887476, 35.57339217195826 );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Wvision2).title("World vision")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.worldvision1)));

        LatLng Drc = new LatLng(33.892777808313056, 35.52051074415333 );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Drc).title("Danish Refugee Council")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.drc1)));

        LatLng Nrc = new LatLng(33.897930365217256,  35.493069449639805 );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Nrc).title("Norwegian Refugee Council")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nrc1)));

        LatLng Oxfam1 = new LatLng(33.88743623998913, 35.50865875340152 );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Oxfam1).title("OXFAM")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.oxfam1)));
        LatLng Oxfam2 = new LatLng(33.8484475255134, 35.91956548906049 );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Oxfam2).title("OXFAM")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.oxfam1)));
        LatLng Oxfam3 = new LatLng(34.42224203429102, 35.827192870916654);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Oxfam3).title("OXFAM")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.oxfam1)));

        LatLng Wfp = new LatLng(33.89447500501417, 35.50479228624766);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Wfp).title("World Food Programme")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.wfp1)));

        LatLng Unhcr = new LatLng(33.897930365217256, 35.501776697895714);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Unhcr).title("United Nations High Commissioner for Refugees")
                .icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.unhcr1)));
    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    fetchLastLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    private BitmapDescriptor BitmapFromVector(Context context, int vectorResId) {
        // below line is use to generate a drawable.
        Drawable vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId);

        // below line is use to set bounds to our vector drawable.
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(1, 1, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

        // below line is use to create a bitmap for our
        // drawable which we have added.
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // below line is use to add bitmap in our canvas.
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        // below line is use to draw our
        // vector drawable in canvas.
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);

        // after generating our bitmap we are returning our bitmap.
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

here's my manifest code related to maps:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

In my build.graddle code I added :

```
 google()
        jcenter()
```

and here's my build.graddle.appname code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayVersion"
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayVersion"
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that relates to maps creation and whats happening onPause. It will help someone diagnose the issue.

Comment: @TDIScott on It

Comment: try moving the `fetchLastLocation();` to the `onResume()` method.

Comment: @TDIScott ok i'll try then test it and comeback to you thank you !!

Comment: @TDIScott I  called the `fetchLastLocation();` in the `onResume()` and it didn't work

Comment: @TDIScott and just to be clear doesn't android studio takes the `onCreate()` as the `onResume()` function by default

Comment: From the android lifecycle, onCreate() then onResume() is called when the activity is started. When putting the app from background to foreground, only onResume() would be called.
You can view the diagram from here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/images/activity_lifecycle.png

As for the question at hand... That can only leave that the Task is failing, as your only setting the markers on the Task being successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out everything's coded right but there's one step that I didn't know of, I should've went into the google cloud platform and enabled the google maps SDK for my API key, so I went and did that and then redownloaded the `google-services.json` from the firebase (back-end I'm using) and replaced the old one in my app's folder with the new .json file. What was happening is that my API key added was not enabled for external use so when I was opening my google maps application(the official app) my App's API key was substituted by the google maps official one, and that's why my application's app wasn't functioning unless I open the google maps official application and then close it. So I did that and everything's working fine.